# Ajax Canvas Image and other variables

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, canvas

My application is MVC 5, I am trying to send canvas image and other variables to the controller using:

```
$("#btnSave1").click(function () {
    var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
    image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Home")',
        data: {
            "imageData" :  image,
            "varx": myvar
        },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert('Image saved successfully !');
        }
    });
});
```

It does not post to the controller.  However if I change data to:

```
 data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
```

It works!  Can I send canvas image and other variables to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I removed

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

It worked.